# Angular select all filtered Items using Pipes and CDK Virtuall Scroll

Tags: angular, typescript, dom, angular-material

I have a large list with an average count of 1000-2000 items, which all items always have to be loaded because the user can select each item separately and config the item or select all items and do a bulk config.

With large lists there are always performance problems so I had to implement CDK Virtuall Scroll to size down the DOM. Without virtuall scroll there are scrolling performance problems.

```
<table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <mat-checkbox color="accent" (change)="selectAllItems($event.checked)">
            </mat-checkbox>
        </th>
     ...
     code
     ...
    </tr>
   </thead>
  <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="85" class="virtual-scroll-viewport">
    <tbody class="virtual-scroll-viewport">
      <tr *cdkVirtualFor="let item of items | filterPipe1: filterPipe1Value1 | filterPipe2: filterPipe1Value2">
      <td [attr.id]="item.id">
          <mat-checkbox color="primary"
                  (change)="changeItemSelection($event, item)"
                  [checked]="isItemSelected(item.id)">
          </mat-checkbox>
      </td>
       ...
       code
       ...
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
</table>
```

Now to the question - How can I select all **filtered** items if I click the selectAllItems checkbox in a performant way?

I have already tryed filtering the item like
`this.items = this.items.filter(value => value.filterValue1 === this.filterPipe1Value1)`
but I get performance problems when using this.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular Team has not implemented a filter pipe and the reason is: Bad performance. The pipe runs on any changes. So you set one item to **selected** (and you change a value what Angular will detect), the pipe checks all items again. That's why you shouldn't use a pipe.

So filter your items without a pipe. Handle it inside the code like:

```
const allItems = [{key: 1, data: "test"}, {key: 2, data: "test2"}, {key: 3, data: "test3"}];
let filteredItems = [...allItems.filter(f => f.key > 2)];
```

And then bind the filteredItems to your list/scroll viewport.

So the select all function will run fast and without any performance issues.

By the way: This is not a workaround. This is the recommended way.

Greetings, Flo.